# Head or Tails code - Beginner Python developing

Tags: python-3.x

In my Heads or Tails code, randomly it will yield incorrect results. For example, I will type in Heads and the computer will choose Tails and the display would say You Win! instead of You lose! or both inputs can be Heads and the display will say You lose!

Below is the code. I have it to ask Heads or Tails and once user input is submitted, I used the random function to randomly choose one of the two and if they match, the display will show You win and You lose if there isn't a match. Lastly, once it's been determined the result, it will ask if you want to continue. I'm wanting the code to consistently give the correct result.

import random

while True:
user_choice1 = 'Heads'
user_choice2 = 'Tails'

```
user_input = input('Heads or Tails? ')
CPU = ['Heads', 'Tails']

print(random.choice(CPU))

if user_input == user_choice1 and random.choice(CPU) == user_choice1:
    print('You win!')
else:
    print('You lose!')

answer1 = 'Yes'
answer2 = 'No'

user_input2 = input('Continue? Yes or No? ')

if user_input2 != answer1:
    break
```

Comment: `random.choice` returns a randomly selected element from its arguments. It does that every time it is called. How many times should your code be calling it each round?

Comment: Are you also checking for user_input being equals to user_choice2 as you are doing for user_choice1?

Comment: I assume the code is calling random.choice once each round. I am a complete novice, so I don't quite understand functions just yet. After looking at the code again, I suppose I could create another if statement to include choice2? I there another function I could use other than random.choice()?